# Show Stacked Markers on React-Native-Maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

When I have multiple markers near the same coordinates, it becomes almost impossible to distingish between the two. Is there a way to "fan" out the markers once you get closer?

I am using custom Markers that look like this:

[image: Markers]

```
<Marker coordinate={{ latitude, longitude, }} onPress={onPress} onSelect={onPress} key={index}>
  <View style={{ borderRadius: 50, height: 15, width: 15, }} />
</Marker>
```